# Angular 8 make button disable based on parent class

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Hi need to make button [disable] if nav have class 'done' or 'active' which is always added dynamically.

Template:

```
<div
 class="nav"
 *ngFor="let step of steps; let stepIndex = index"
 [ngClass]="{
  done: step.done,
  active: stepIndex == selectedIndex
  }"
 >
 <button class="btn"></button>
</div>
```

I am not sure how to do this, so looking for some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access the DOM element, example:

```
<div #div1 class="foobar hero">
  I am a div with any class
  <button class="btn" [disabled]="div1.classList.contains('done') || div1.classList.contains('active')">Button</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div #div2>
  I am a div with no class
  <button class="btn" [disabled]="div2.classList.contains('done') || div2.classList.contains('active')">Button</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div #div3 class="done">
  I am a div with done class
  <button class="btn" [disabled]="div3.classList.contains('done') || div3.classList.contains('active')">Button</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div #div4 class="active">
  I am a div with active class
  <button class="btn" [disabled]="div4.classList.contains('done') || div4.classList.contains('active')">Button</button>
</div>
<hr>
```

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qjsvfi?file=src/app/app.component.html

Edit:
It seems like you are using bootstrap, you might want to think about setting the disabled class instead of the property.

```
<button class="btn" [ngClass]="{ disabled: div4.classList.contains('done') || div4.classList.contains('active') }">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
<button [disabled]="step.done || stepIndex == selectedIndex" class="btn"></button>
```

Comment: Thank you @kirubel, but I need to add disabled based on parent class only.

Comment: I've updated my answer. So if `step.done` you're setting the class to `done` and if `stepIndex == selectedIndex` your class is `active`. In such condition you can play with the `[disabled]` attribute of the button as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the conditions again in the `[disabled]` property of the button. Try the following

```html
<div
  class="nav"
  *ngFor="let step of steps; let stepIndex = index"
  [ngClass]="{
    done: step.done,
    active: stepIndex == selectedIndex
  }">

  <button class="btn" [disabled]="step.done || stepIndex == selectedIndex"></button>
</div>
```